# Mathematical matrix program

Tags: c, math, matrix, logic, codeblocks

I'm currently creating a matrix program that can display the matrix with our input, the trace of the matrix, ability to create 2x2 matrix from original matrix, the determinant of the matrix, the submatrix, and have ability to delete the rows and columns in the matrix, here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct matrix
{
    char name;
    int mValues[10][10];
    int nrows;
    int ncols;
};
struct matrix2
{
    char name2;
    int mValues2[10][10];
    int nrows2;
    int ncols2;
};
int main()
{
    struct matrix M1, M2;
    int trace;
    int determinant;

        matrixInput(&M1);
        matrixDisplay(M1);
        matrixTrace(M1, &trace);
        printf("\nThe trace of matrix is %d",trace);

    return 0;
}


void matrixInput(struct matrix *mat)
{
    printf("Please enter a one character name for the matrix, e.g A, B, etc:");
        scanf("%c",&(*mat).name);

    printf("\nEnter # rows of the matrix(<10):\n");
        scanf("%d",&(*mat).nrows);

    printf("Enter # columns of the matrix(<10):\n");
        scanf("%d",&(*mat).ncols);

    printf("\nMatrix %c:\n",(*mat).name);

    FILE *file = fopen("matrix.txt","r");

    for(int x =0; x < (*mat).nrows; x++) {
        for(int y=0; y < (*mat).ncols; y++) {
            fscanf(file, "%d", &(*mat).mValues[x][y]);
        }
    }
    fclose(file);

}

void matrixDisplay(struct matrix mat)
{
    int baris, kolom;

    for(baris = 0; baris < mat.nrows; baris++) {
        printf("Row %d: ", baris);
        for(kolom = 0; kolom < mat.ncols; kolom++) {
            printf("\t%d", mat.mValues[baris][kolom]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    getchar();
    return;
}

void matrixTrace(struct matrix mat, int *trace)
{
    int baris, kolom;
    *trace = 0;
    for(baris = 0; baris < mat.nrows; baris++){
        for(kolom = 0; kolom < mat.ncols; kolom++){
        if(baris == kolom){
    *trace += mat.mValues[baris][kolom];}


    }
    }
}
   void matrixInput2(struct matrix2 *mat2)
{
    printf("Please enter a one character name for the matrix, e.g A, B, etc:");
        scanf("%c",&(*mat2).name2);

    printf("\nEnter row number to start 2x2 matrix, number needs to be between 0 and 2:\n");
        scanf("%d",&(*mat2).nrows2);

    printf("Enter column number to start 2x2 matrix, number needs to be between 0 and 2:\n");
        scanf("%d",&(*mat2).ncols2);
        printf("\nMatrixInput2 %c:\n",(*mat2).name2);
}
```

here's the example of the output:

```
Please enter a one character name for the matrix, e.g A, B, etc: A

    Enter # rows of the matrix(<10):
    4
    Enter # columns of the matrix(<10):
    4

    Matrix A:
    Row 0:  1      -15     20     -40
    Row 1:  41     -60     75     -99
    Row 2:  100    -150    2      -14
    Row 3:  21     -39     42     -59

    The trace of matrix is =116
```

so the matrix is called in .txt file,i just have finished creating the matrix display and the trace, now i want to create 2x2 matrix from the original matrix, but i can't make input again? the program ends after the output, i try to give it void function but still doesn't works, anyone can help?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [About] and [Ask] pages soon, and (more urgently) read about how to create an MCVE ([MCVE]).  It is not clear what specific problem youo

Comment: Add space `scanf(" %c",&(*mat).name);`.

Answer (score 1):

Now i fix my problem, here is the updated code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct matrix
{
    char name;
    int mValues[10][10];
    int nrows;
    int ncols;
};
struct matrix2
{
    char name2;
    int mValues2[10][10];
    int nrows2;
    int ncols2;
};
int main()
{
    struct matrix m1, *m2;
    int trace;
    int determinant;

        matrixInput(&m1);
        matrixDisplay(m1);
        matrixTrace(m1, &trace);
        printf("\nThe trace of matrix is %d",trace);
        matrixDeterminant(*m2, &determinant);

    return 0;
}


void matrixInput(struct matrix *mat, struct matrix2 *mat2)
{
    printf("Please enter a one character name for the matrix, e.g A, B, etc:");
        scanf("%c",&(*mat).name);

    printf("\nEnter # rows of the matrix(<10):\n");
        scanf("%d",&(*mat).nrows);

    printf("Enter # columns of the matrix(<10):\n");
        scanf("%d",&(*mat).ncols);

    printf("\nMatrix %c:\n",(*mat).name);

    FILE *file = fopen("matrix.txt","r");

    for(int x =0; x < (*mat).nrows; x++) {
        for(int y=0; y < (*mat).ncols; y++) {
            fscanf(file, "%d", &(*mat).mValues[x][y]);
        }
    }
    fclose(file);

}

void matrixDeterminant(struct matrix m1, struct matrix2 *m2,struct matrix2 *mat2, int *determinant)
{

    printf("\n\nFinding the determinant now!");
    printf("\nPlease enter a one character name for the matrix, e.g A, B, etc:");
        scanf("%c",&(*m2).name2);

    printf("\nEnter row number where to start 2x2 matrix, number needs to be between 0 and 2:\n");
        scanf("%d",&(*m2).nrows2);

    printf("Enter column number where to start 2x2 matrix, number needs to be between 0 and 2:\n");
        scanf("%d",&(*m2).ncols2);

    }

void matrixDisplay(struct matrix mat)
{
    int baris, kolom;
    for(baris = 0; baris < mat.nrows; baris++) {
        printf("Row %d: ", baris);
        for(kolom = 0; kolom < mat.ncols; kolom++) {
            printf("\t%d", mat.mValues[baris][kolom]);
        }
        printf("\n");

    }
    getchar();
    return;
}

void matrixTrace(struct matrix mat, int *trace)
{
    int baris, kolom;
    *trace = 0;
    for(baris = 0; baris < mat.nrows; baris++){
        for(kolom = 0; kolom < mat.ncols; kolom++){
        if(baris == kolom){
    *trace += mat.mValues[baris][kolom];}

    }

}
}
```

another thing is that i want to create a 2x2 matrix from the original matrix and find the determinant of the matrix,the matrix is called from a txt file that i create, i'm very confused, what should i type next?

i want the output to be like this:

```
Please enter a one character name for the matrix, e.g A, B, etc: A

Enter # rows of the matrix(<10):
4
Enter # columns of the matrix(<10):
4

Matrix A:
Row 0:  1      -15     20     -40
Row 1:  41     -60     75     -99
Row 2:  100    -150    2      -14
Row 3:  21     -39     42     -59

The trace of matrix is =116

Finding the determinant now!
Please enter a one character name for the matrix, e.g A, B, etc: B
Enter row number where to start 2x2 matrix, number needs to be between 0 and 2:x

Enter column number where to start 2x2 matrix, number needs to be between 0 and 2:x

The determinant is x for
Matrix B:

Row 0:  x      x  
Row 1:  x      x
```

The new 2x2 matrix is saved in a new struct, how can i do that?